# Simplest way to read data from a txt file

Tags: c++

I want to store the contents of a .txt file as attributes of different objects which I can then store in a vector. Is there a simple way to do this.

My txt file looks like this:

```
a0 0 4 0 10
a1 0 3 0 20
a2 0 2 0 30
```

I tried to do it like this but i get an error.

```
class process {
    public:
        std::string name;
        int arrivalTime;
        int priority;
        int age;
        int ticketsReq;
        int time;

        process(std::string name, int arrivalTime, int priority, int age, int ticketsReq) {
            this->name = name;
            this->arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
            this->priority = priority;
            this->age = age;
            this->ticketsReq = ticketsReq;
            this->time = 0;

        }
  };

int main() {
  std::ifstream theFile("input.txt");
  int i = 0;
  std::vector<process> a;
  std::string nameT;
  int arrivalTimeT;
  int priorityT;
  int ageT;
  int ticketsReqT;
  int timeT;

  while(theFile>>nameT>>arrivalTimeT>>priorityT>>ageT>>ticketsReqT){
    a[i] = process (nameT,arrivalTimeT,priorityT,ageT,ticketsReqT);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) "_I tried to do it like this but i get an error._" What error? 2) `a[i]`, for any value of `i`, is undefined behavior, due to `std::vector` being empty. Did you mean `a.emplace_back (nameT,arrivalTimeT,priorityT,ageT,ticketsReqT);`?

Comment: One "error" is that you try to index into an empty vector. If it's *the* error you're asking about or not I don't know.

Comment: And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: ah, i thought vectors were used in the same way as arrays. Is there any other simpler data structure that doesnot need a size to be defined to hold such objects? Sorry, I just moved from java to c++ and I find it very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I see at least one problem.

First, vector assumes you call push_back to add elements to the vector. You can do vector[index] to access an element once it exists. But you're going to get a range problem with that.

Second, this line doesn't make sense:

```
a[i] = process (nameT,arrivalTimeT,priorityT,ageT,ticketsReqT);
```

At the point you do this, you don't have a "this" for process. You would need to do something like:

```
process myObj(nameT,arrivalTimeT,priorityT,ageT,ticketsReqT);
a.push_back(myObj);
```

As a side-point, I personally never store objects in std::vector. I store pointers to objects. I don't know if someone else can comment on this, but consider what happens. You may want to write a simpler example to test that.

Comment: What is the problem with `a[i] = process (nameT,arrivalTimeT,priorityT,ageT,ticketsReqT);`? It creates a temporary `process` and move-assigns it to `a[i]`. (Of course you are right that `a[i]` must exist first.)

Comment: `vector`s of pointers to objects injects an extra layer of pointer-chasing into the mix. Sometimes this results in poor cache behaviour and thus poor performance. `vector` is usually at its best directly holding objects. `vector` can also simplify lifetime management.